# how to select attribute value and creates substrings Using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

**Question EDITED**

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Results.xsl"?>
  <TestCase>
    <Details>

    <platform>Windows 7-Firefox\prod</platform>

    </Details>
  </TestCase>
```

I need to retrieve Windows 7 Firefox prod as individual strings im able to retrieve all the strings except "Firefox", please help to to retrieve it

My XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>


       <OS><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(TestCase/Details/platform, '-')"/></OS>
<inst><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(TestCase/Details/platform, '\')"/></inst>

<brow><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(TestCase/Details/platform, '\'),'-')"> </brow>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the hyphen is always used as a delimiter (and does not ever appear in either the OS name or the browser name), you can use the `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions here

```
<OS><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(TestCase/Details/platform, '-')"/></OS>
<Browser><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(TestCase/Details/platform, '-')"/></Browser>
```

Comment: Hi how can i add expand collapse feature to it please provide XSL code so that when i click a hyperlink it must expand PLATFORM details again clicking same hyperlink PLATFORM  details should be invisible

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, so you need to make an attempt to solve this yourself, and ask a question when you run into problems. Having said that, the expand/collapse feature is not actually an XSLT issue. First you have to work out how to do it in just HTML/JavaScript, then you can write the XSLT to transform your XML into it (which should then be quite straight-forward once you know what to aim for). As a starter, consider using the JQuery "toggle" function. See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/